# Yocto fetchall and populate_sdk

Tags: yocto

I am seeing that bitbake -c fetchall \some_image\ does not allow for getting all packages related to building the sdk for \some_image.  So bitbake -c populate_sdk \some_image\ fails when I don't have an internet connection and bitbake can't download packages.

Is there a way to tell bitbake -c fetchall \for_populate_sdk_bitbake\?

Thanks
Y-

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run `bitbake -c fetchall --continue universe`. It may displays error, but don't care about.

You'll download all packages listed by `bitbake -s`.
I have tested on `jethro` branch and it works fine for me.